# nginx url rewrite inside location

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, nginx

I have two application running in 8080 & 5999 ports . I want use nginx to proxy two application as `/rss` & `/demo` .

But the problem I'm facing is that css, javascript are not loading .

```
location /rss {
  rewrite ^/rss(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
  proxy_redirect off;
}

location /demo {
  rewrite ^/demo(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5999/;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Can someone please help me correct this one ...

Comment: what is the URL of the css and javascript in the browser inspector? and are they returning 404 ?

Comment: Yes it's 404.  as it's looking for the static contents under docroot.

Comment: Do they physically exist in the root folder, or do they need to be proxied to work ?

Comment: it has to be picked up from the proxy_pass i.e. http://localhost:8080 .

Comment: check the log of the server being proxied to, I'm assuming the URLs are passed with a wrong prefix or something, try removing the trailing slash in the `proxy_pass` lines for example

Comment: `location /rss {
      rewrite ^/rss(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost8080; proxy_redirect off; }` Still no luck. 1st request is going to the proxy , but other subsequent requests are still going to the "location /"  .

Comment: maybe what you need is to only rewrite if it's not an existing file or directory: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think the below is a bit neater (avoiding double slashes in the proxied request):

```nginxconf
location /rss/ {
  rewrite ^/rss(/.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_redirect off;
}

location /demo/ {
  rewrite ^/demo(/.*)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5999;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Secondly, you need to make sure your CSS, etc. is being referenced in your HTML correctly.

If a CSS file was referenced like so in the HTML, before proxying:

```
http://localhost:8080/styles/application.css
```

Then you need to somehow make the reference in the HTML like this to account for the new location (including sub-directory) after proxying:

```
http://notproxied.com/rss/styles/application.css
```